# Manga where the main character accidentally kills all monsters in dungeon and becomes number one and awakens a game system ability

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character (MC) was a normal office man. A dungeon appeared in the middle of the city. The MC accidentally pushed a truck on road and it fell into the dungeon, killing all monsters.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[D Genesis: Three Years Since the Dungeon Appeared](https://anilist.co/manga/123591/D-Genesis-Dungeon-ga-Dekite-3nen/)*

> It has been 3 years since the first dungeon, a giant cave filled with monsters, was born. In a world where dungeon raiders are common, Yoshimura, who lives his life as company livestock, **unexpectedly ranks first in the world rankings**! Wishing for a more laidback lifestyle, he retires and decides to enter the dungeon. Wielding unknown skills that he has gotten, he joins the frontline of the dungeon raiders. What will be the future of his laidback life?

While driving back from a company trip, he accidentally runs over a goblin, killing it and granting him a dungeon explorer rank and a D-Card. He accidentally pushes over a truck during an earthquake (presumably caused by a new dungeon appearing).

[image: Truck]

The truck is carrying numerous rebar pipes, which fall and kill everything within the dungeon immediately, granting him experience and a new skill.

[image: Speedrun]

The result of this is that he immediately becomes the top-ranked adventurer in the world.